# Angular animate help - slide and then hide

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

i am trying to achieve a pretty simple effect ( I thought ). When a user clicks on a button, I need to slide in a div from the right side of a 'viewport' onto the viewable page.
at the moment I have the 'slide' div's css to look like this:

```
.slider {
    postion: absolute;
    right: -200;
    display: none
}
```

Once a user clicks on a button, the div needs to show, and then move to the left, i.e.

```
transform: translate(-200px, 0);
```

At the end of the animation the end state of that div would need to be something like this

```
.slider.after-animate {
    postion: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

then when the user 'closes' the div, I want to slide it back to `right: -200px` and then after the animation is done, I want to put a display:none on that div.

I have looked an several ngAnimate tutorials but nothing I could find deals with the 'before/after' animate scenario where I need to show\hide the div before/after it gets animated.
can anyone point me to the right direction ????

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you are using css3. If yes then use its animation instead of angular. Then in angular you just have to toggal classes on click

Comment: um, could you provide an example , i.m not sure what you are trying to explain. is there a better way to go about it than using css3 transform ?

Comment: This link might helps u. http://forums.asp.net/t/1887542.aspx?show+hide+div+with+css3+transition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [css keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) so that we have more than 2 states. In this example, there are 3 states for each animation.

```
.slider 
{
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;

  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:red;
}

//angular animate automatically adds ng-hide-add when starting to add ng-hide class
.slider.ng-hide-add{
  -webkit-animation: remove_sequence 2s linear ;
  animation:remove_sequence 2s linear;

  display:block!important;
}

//angular animate automatically adds ng-hide-add when starting to remove ng-hide class
.slider.ng-hide-remove{
  -webkit-animation: enter_sequence 2s linear ;
  animation:enter_sequence 2s linear;

  display:block!important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes enter_sequence {
  0% { display:block; 
    right:-200px;
  }
  10% { right:-200px; }
  100% {right:0px;}
}

@keyframes enter_sequence {
  0% { display:block; 
    right:-200px;
  }
  10% { right:-200px; }
  100% {right:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes remove_sequence {
  0% { right:0px; }
  90% { right:-200px; }
  100% {
    right:-200px;
    display:none;

  }
}

@keyframes remove_sequence {
  0% { right:0px; }
  90% { right:-200px; }
  100% {
    right:-200px;
    display:none;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JP3AZC5F9DqdsPUONADn?p=catalogue)